# animations or transform method?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I want to move a div after clicking on a button If I write this css:

```
div.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -ms-transform: translate(50px, 100px);  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(50px, 100px);  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(50px, 100px);  /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Then the problem is that when I Open the Page I dont see the div's movement so I have to use animation and if I use animation the problem is that the div will start automatically to move.
My question is what should I use? animation or transform? how can I ?

Comment: how are you able to keep the state of the `div` on page load?

Comment: state of div has been changed when i open the page but i dont see the movement (like animation) sry my english is not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery.

css:

```
div.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition-duration=2s; //or any duration else
}
```

jquery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".box").css({
    "transform": "translate(50px,100px)",
    "-webkit-transform": "translate(50px,100px)",
    "-ms-transform": "translate(50px,100px)"
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/eylay/3rp6bqka/)

Comment: Your edit didn't add any value to your post. Why do edit again?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with just CSS3! Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fo6zktjo/):

Create a `<label>` and `<input>` elements:

```
<label class="label-btn" for="clickme">Click me!</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="clickme" />    
<div class="box"></div>
```

Then, apply this little trick CSS for the checkbox and style your label as if it was a button:

```
#clickme {
    display: none;
}

#clickme:checked + div.box {
  -ms-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* Safari */
  transform: translate(50px,100px); /* Standard syntax */
}

.label-btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    background: pink;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Also, add an transition property to your div.box so the transform can run smoothly (change the transition time if you want):

```
div.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 1s all;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes It helped. Its so great you didnt use java or jquery. nice idea